# Is there any way of expanding Visual studio Intellisense for .cs files?

Tags: autocomplete, addition, intellisense, expand

I was wondering if it is possible to expand Visual Studio Intellisense for displaying custom statement completition in .cs files. I.e. I have found some examples of using xsd schemas to expand intellisense but they are for custom xml files if I'm not mistaken. What I would like to do is add some additional "options" to intellisense by adding just a string that will appear. Something like "MyCustomIntellisenseOption" and when I start writing I will get it in intellisense. I have found a similar solution [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372314%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), but although it works exactly like I want it with a slight modification where I changed:

```
[Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
[Name("token completion handler")]
[ContentType("plaintext")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
internal class TestCompletionHandlerProvider : IVsTextViewCreationListener
```

to:

```
[Export(typeof(IVsTextViewCreationListener))]
[Name("token completion handler")]
[ContentType("CSharp")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Editable)]
internal class TestCompletionHandlerProvider : IVsTextViewCreationListener
```

But that gives me another problem.
If I have two strings "AddSomething.SomethingElse.Something1" and "AddSomething.SomethingElse.Something2" whenever I try to type the second string I come to the .(dot) and autocomplete kicks in and selects first option. Is it possible to override the dot? I figured that it has something to do with Token triggers but it seems I'm not able to find a solution for this.

The main idea is that those custom strings work like intellisense for classes but with predefined fixed strings.

Is there any other possible solution for adding custom intellisense and autocomplete option? Or a solution for my .(dot) problem?

Thank you in advance.